# Phone Field in Custom Object

Tags: validation, formula-field, validation-rule

When I add Phone field in custom Object, I want to the user to enter minimum of 10 digits, if the user enters less than 10 digits they should get error [Just the numbers, no need of any special characters inclusion like +1 (666) 777-8910 just '6667778910']. Can anyone please help me with the **formula** for this criteria to enter in **validation rule**?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @crmprogdev mentioned, I would recommend to use RegEx. See this example for US Phone number has 10 digits in (999) 999-9999 format: `NOT(REGEX(Phone, "\\D*?(\\d\\D*?){10}"))` in [UsefulValidationRules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulValidationRules.meta/usefulValidationRules/)

If you don't like RegEx, you can use an alternativly an onion-like SUBSTITUTE. If you need other characters excluded, you'll have to add more SUBSTITUTEs. TRIM removes white space and LEN counts the cleaned results:

```
 LEN(
   SUBSTITUTE(
     SUBSTITUTE(
       SUBSTITUTE( 
         TRIM(YourFieled__c) 
       , "+", "")
     , "(", "")
   , ")", "")
 ) < 10
```

See also

- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm#text_functions

Comment: Actually, you can use RegEx to replace characters. See this example for US Phone number has 10 digits in (999) 999-9999 format:  `NOT(REGEX(Phone, "\\D*?(\\d\\D*?){10}"))` in [UsefulValidationRules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulValidationRules.meta/usefulValidationRules/). This could be modified to handle other situations as well.

Comment: @crmprogdev - thanks for your headsup, you are right. I updated my answer.